# Best practice when building front end login for wordpress using ajax with nonce/caching

Tags: ajax, wordpress, caching, nonce

I have built some functionality into my WordPress theme to allow users to register and login through the front end using ajax functionality to verify and register/log the user in.

My question is regarding the nonce. Because I use a caching plugin, for a certain period of time between the nonce expiring and the page cache refreshing, the page displays an expired nonce, and therefore the ajax login does not work and it's sending the old cached nonce.

My question is, what is the best practice for this situation?

As I see it I have several options:

- 1 Remove the nonce completely for login/registration and just leave it open so anyone can try to log in/register directly through ajax. Is this a security issue or is it standard?
- 2 Somehow load the nonce dynamically through another ajax request to bypass the caching feature.
- 3 Build my own nonce system that also refreshes the cache when the nonce is updated (seems overkill).

I feel like this should be fairly standard and I shouldn't have to re-invent the wheel but I can't seem to find an answer. I've seen some people online say one should just refresh the cache more often, but even then, from my calculations, there would still be a period of time when the nonce expires and the cache refreshes where the nonce would be invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. A new nonce gets generated every 12 hours, but each nonce is still valid for 24 hours. So as long as I set the cache to expire in under 12 hours, it will still be valid. Problem solved!

Comment: what about if you login as a different user or logout?  I'm having issues with the nonces caching and haven't found a work around yet.